# When pointing to a github repo with Cocoapods, is there a way to specify a subfolder?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm using a fork of a repo that contains a larger project and an SDK in a subfolder. The podspec has a `source_files` property that configures the subfolder, but the top-level repo has no knowledge of the podspec, and so pointing to:

```
pod 'PodName', :git => 'https://github.com/owner/project.git'
```

... fails because there's no podspec in the root. Is there a way to specify using a subfolder when pointing Cocoapods to a git repo?

Something like:

```
pod 'PodName', :git => 'https://github.com/owner/project.git', :subfolder => '/subfolder/path/to/podspec'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to do this by pointing to the raw file on github and using the podspec option. Cocoapods is expecting the pod spec to be in the root directory with all of the `:git =>` options but you can point directly to a file using the `:podspec =>` option.

```
pod 'PodName', :podspec => 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owner/project/branch/subfolder/project.podspec'
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when using this approach in my Podfile. Any advice for using this approach where the git repo is private?

Comment: @AaronWasserman Did you find a way to do this for private repo?

Comment: You need to add the token parameter, but that changes from time to time.